# Just uploaded my Laravel 8 tiny project and no more views except index printed

Tags: laravel, upload

I have just finished a small project under LARAVEL 8, and I am trying to upload it but we cannot access the other pages of the site. Only the index (maybe a blade problem?) seems to work.
No worries in local.

I tested the following changes:

- the index.php file with the files moved from the public folder to the root directory
- the proxi file of a middleware with this value = '*';
- and of course the .env file with the right info of the server that hosts me

Any idea to fix every routes? thanks

Comment: Hi, show what you have done, if possible with screenshots

Comment: In my experience, whenever i get this error, its down to NGINX configuration of the server.

Comment: usually because pretty urls/rewriting are not working/configured on the webserver